# C# Enum Type Scope Inside Static Class

Tags: c#, class, enums, scope

I have an *enum* inside a *public* class defined as follows:

```
namespace NS1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public enum ModeEnum { Auto, Manual };
    }
}
```

I also have a static class where I am trying to use this enum type (note they both belong to the same namespace):

```
namespace NS1
{
    public static class MyStaticClass
    {
        public static MyClass.ModeEnum mode = MyClass.ModeEnum.Auto;
    }
}
```

*MyStaticClass* will not compile. The compiler gives the following error:

*The type name 'ModeEnum' does not exist in the type 'NS1.MyStaticClass.MyClass.ModeEnum'*

If I change the definition for *mode* to the following:

```
public static ModeEnum mode = ModeEnum.Auto;
```

I get a slightly different error:

*The type or namespace name 'ModeEnum' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

This second error I kind of anticipated because in the past when referencing *enum* types I have always had to qualify it with the *class* name first followed by the *enum type name*.

```
<Class Name>.<Enum Name> myValue = <Class Name>.<Enum Name>.<Enum Value>
```

This brings up another question I have been meaning to ask.. Sometimes when I declare a variable of type *enum* I have to add the *namespace* name as well, even though my class has the correct *using* statement. For example:

```
<Namespace Name>.<Class Name>.<Enum Name> myValue = <Namespace Name>.<Class Name>.<Enum Name>.<Enum Value>
```

This leads to some strange looking variable declarations. For example, in one of my classes I have an *enum* variable that looks like the following:

```
using namespace NS1;
...
...
NS1.MyClass.ModeEnum myMode = NS1.MyClass.ModeEnum.Auto;
```

Can anyone point out to me why and when you need to qualify things with the namespace first?

I tried to figure it out but I have frankly been too busy to *learn* what's going on. I just went with the easy fix of adding the namespace name. :P

Comment: If you put your example code in a new project, does it fail for you?  It works just fine for me...

Comment: Good idea... I will try that now. :)

Comment: Also FYI -- an `enum` is not _required_ to be defined in a class.

Comment: Ah, so it can be defined below the namespace declaration and above the class defintion?

Comment: That's also probably the right place for it too.  I would put an enum inside of a class if it is only used from within that class.

Comment: Is your namespace name the same as your class name?  Is your class name the same as your enum name?  (Is there a namespace that is the same as your class name, or a class that is the same name as your namespace name?) If any of those are true, or if there are multiple things that each could resolve to it's the likely root of your problem.  [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a second type called MyClass, one inside the static class, one outside?

Comment: I believe Servy might be onto something... yes NS name is the same as the class name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message it seems that you have *two* `MyClass`, and the one you haven't told us about is *inside* `MyStaticClass`.

It looks you're confusing yourself by nesting types. Don't put classes or enums inside other classes unless you have a good reason. It's easier to have all classes and enums directly under the namespace.

**EDIT**: I just see in the comments (of the question, not below) that the problem is that the namespace and the type inside it have the same name.

Comment: @JanTacci You can use these kinds of types in C#: `class`, `delegate`, `enum`, `interface`, and `struct`. Each of them can be defined on the namespace level **or** be put inside an outer class (or outer struct).